# Drawing data from "population" for regression analysis

Tags: regression

We have a response variable $Y$ and predictor $X$, and we draw $n$ samples $(Y_1,X_1), \ldots, (Y_n, X_n)$ from the population of interest to do a regression analysis. Under the assumptions of a simple linear regression model, my question is a conceptual one: how do we really think about the response on the $i$th unit, $Y_i$? Do we say it's drawn from the level or subpopulation of individuals with $ X = x_i $, or from the aggregate population over all the values of $X$? Moreover, while we assume that the response $Y$ in every subpopulation defined by $X$ is normal with equal variances, how do we think about the aggregate population from which $Y_i$ is drawn?

Answer (score 1):

In regression analysis each response $Y_i$ is modelled conditional on the observed predictor value $x_i$; as (with a normal distribution of errors) $Y_i\sim\mathcal{N}(\beta_0+\beta_1 x_i,\sigma^2)$ where $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ are the intercept & slope coefficients respectively, and $\sigma^2$ is the common error variance. Just as if the $x_i$s had been set by an experimenter rather than themselves sampled. The marginal distribution of the $Y_i$s is not necessarily thought about at all; but can be obtained using the conditional model, for any assumed distribution of the $X_i$s.

Marginal models are sometimes used for panel/longitudinal data instead of conditional multi-level models with random effects. See [Lee & Nelder (2004), "Conditional and Marginal Models: Another View", *Statistical Science*, **19**, 2](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ss/1105714159) for a (rather critical) account.